# Using NLP can we create a summary of functional specification

Tags: requirements, natural-language-processing

Just thinking that is it somehow possible by using Language processing APIs to extract a must have points or an intelligent summary from documents like functional specifications ..

Comment: Anything's possible if you have a hundred million dollars in funding, except for a working healthcare.gov website.

Comment: This is the programming equivalent of a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: somebody will do it someday ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) is able to process human documents and do some interesting things, like judge the "[sentiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis)" of the document or note similarities with other documents in a [corpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus). There have been a number of attempts to automagically summarize documents.

However, the quality of those summaries varies from "Wow! That was pretty good!" to "This is complete rubbish." Unfortunately, the curve is biased toward the less-good end of the spectrum. For applications where you have a truly overwhelming number of input documents, and where some amount of erroneous summarization is not a show-stopper, maybe. But with product specifications, you're talking about very technical documents for which missing a few points could be missing the entire point of the spec, and for which getting a few details wrong can mean not just a useless, but a counter-productive, summary.

NLP is best left to applications where errors and omissions carry lower risks.

Comment: Thanks for reply , do you agree somewhere that vocabulary  used in specification document is actually limited or I am not correct ...

Comment: The vocabulary is limited, but some parts of it are also very technical / precise. So it's a "perturbable" data set. Small changes in interpretation can lead to large differences in output.

Comment: thanks for reply that helped ... If I limit myself only to extracting the validations of fields ...  will that be a positive scenario ...